# Export test/Pipeline reports from Analytics tab in Azure build Pipeline and attach them with an email notification

Tags: azure-devops, report, azure-pipelines

Unable to figure out a way to export test/Pipeline reports from Analytics tab in Azure build Pipeline and attach them to an email notification. Please guide.

[Analytics tab in Azure build pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G572e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot attach them to notification.

As a workaround, we could capture the REST API via F12->add task power shell to get the response body and save it to a file.

Power shell script:

```
$outfile = "{file path}"
$connectionToken="$(pat)"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$PipelineReportURL = "{URL}" 
$PipelineReportInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PipelineReportURL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get –OutFile $outfile
```

Install the extension [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask&ssr=false#overview) and use the task `Send email` to get the email notification that the pipeline has just run.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, Do we need to replace  $AuditLogURL with $PipelineReportURL ? or does $AuditLogURL have another value ? and can we use any variables while passing the Pipeline/Test report url

Comment: I have worked previously with API's to trigger build/release pipelines, I tried using it but i get the report as html file

Comment: Sorry, we need to replace $AuditLogURL with $PipelineReportURL, this is my mistake, we could convert the html file to json file.

Comment: Hi @saikumarreddy, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?